# Converting nested SQL statement to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I need help to figure out how the following sql statement can be converted into a linq statement

```
SELECT distinct tableA.x, tableA.y, tableA.z
FROM tableA inner join
     tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id inner join
     tableC on tableA.id = tableC.id
WHERE (tableB.columnOne IN (SELECT tableX.columnOne
                            FROM tableX INNER JOIN
                            tableY ON tableX.xId = tableY.xId
                            WHERE (tableY.xId = tableC.xId) ) 
AND (tableB.columnTwo IN  (SELECT tableXx.columnTwo
                            FROM tableXx INNER JOIN
                            tableYy ON tableXx.XxId = tableYy.XxId
                            WHERE tableYy.XxId =tableC.XxId))) 
)
```

Comment: Don't just dump SQL and ask for conversion. *At least* show a class model to start with and you own first efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the first thing to point out is that you can do sub queries in LINQ. Within your main Where clause, you could probably create queries for your subqueries, (which would result in IQueryable types) and then use .Any() to predict if there are any matches e.g.

```
var tableXquery = {my tableX subquery};
var tableXxquery = {my tableXx subquery};

var result = context.tableB.where(b => tableXquery.any(x => x.columnOne == b.columnOne) && xx => tableXxquery.any(xx => xx.columnTwo == b.columnTwo));
```

I hope you get the idea - I just tend to put queries where they need to be, and let LINQ sort it out!